# Actual impact of deprecation of login.microsoftonline.com for B2C tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am a bit confused by the wording on the [announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/b2c-deprecate-msol/) for the deprecation of login.microsoftonline.com for "*B2C tenants*".

> New tenants created after this announcement will no longer be able to accept requests from login.microsoftonline.com.

My main concern is: How will this affect the [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#daemonsserver-side-applications) grant? As far as I can see, this is only supported via login.microsoftonline.com.

> Although client credential flow is not currently supported by Azure AD B2C, you can set up client credential flow using Azure AD. An Azure AD B2C tenant shares some functionality with Azure AD enterprise tenants. The client credential flow is supported using the Azure AD functionality of the Azure AD B2C tenant.

**Will the "Azure AD functionality" continue to work with login.microsoftonline.com indefinitely?** If so, where can I draw the line of what this actually means?

I have created a new B2C tenant after the announcement. So far, everything works, even the B2C user flows via login.microsoftonline.com. The only difference at the moment is that I don't get the domain selection when I click on "run user flow".

My current understanding would be that *"everything that uses B2C policies must use b2clogin.com"* - everything else must continue to use login.microsoftonline.com.

Without policy:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytesttenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token => working URL
- https://mytesttenant.b2clogin.com/mytesttenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token => 404

With policy:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytesttenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_signupsignin => working URL
- https://mytesttenant.b2clogin.com/mytesttenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_signupsignin => working URL

(my tenant is not actually named mytesttenant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an official answer back via [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46236).

> Use of b2clogin.com is enforced for b2c functionality only. Client Credentials flow is not supported for B2C Applications. Since the App registered via App Registration under Azure AD B2C, can also be used for standard Azure AD as well which supports Client Credentials flow. For standard AAD functionality, use of b2clogin.com is not applicable and requires login.microsoftonline.com only.
>
> For more details, refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#daemonsserver-side-applications

Answer (score 2):

I think you will still be able to use [`client credentials flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) in Azure AD B2C tenant.

The deprecation of `login.microsoftonline.com` just affects the Azure AD B2C functionality. 
However, the client credentials flow is an Azure AD functionality, it should not be affected, the B2C tenant just shares the functionality with the normal Azure AD tenant.

> I have created a new B2C tenant after the announcement. So far, everything works, even the B2C user flows via login.microsoftonline.com. The only difference at the moment is that I don't get the domain selection when I click on "run user flow".

I suppose we can but we should not do this, as the UI has been changed, MS should not want the new users(create B2C tenant after the announcement) of Azure B2C to use `login.microsoftonline.com`, the implementation has not been changed, it will give other users a transition period.

Comment: Thank you for giving your input, this helps me with my impression so far. It is just very unfortunate that the wording on the announcement so vague, and the docs are not really helping either.